# Zebra Label Feeds Blank after printing

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I have a specific label that feeds a second, blank label after printing a good one. I'd imagine it's something about the ZPL code, but I cannot seem to isolate it. I've tried removing each formatting statement at the top, one at a time and trying different values for each one. I've also re-calibrated even though other labels print just fine. Any ideas?

```
~JO
^XA
^PMN
^MNY
^MMR
^MTT
^MD0
^LH0,0
^LL1219
^PR4
^JMA
^FO0,398^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO406,0^FR^GB2,236,2^FS
^FO0,606^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO455,234^FR^GB2,165,2^FS
^FO0,843^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO2,232^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO412,604^FR^GB2,240,2^FS
^FO41,41^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDFrom:^FS
^FO427,41^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDTo:^FS
^FO41,264^BY2,2.0,102^B3N,N,102,N,N^FR^FD^FS
^FO22,248^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FDOrder Number:^FS
^FO463,238^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDCarrier:^FS
^FO488,264^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO22,412^CI0^ABN,22,14^FR^FDORDER#^FS
^FO49,443^CI0^A0N,28,56^FR^FD^FS
^FO41,61^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDRandom Address^FS
^FO41,102^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDOne Industrial Rd^FS
^FO41,122^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDSuite 199^FS
^FO41,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDThistown, PA 12345^FS
^FO20,508^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FDP.O.#^FS
^FO366,508^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FDSHIP DATE^FS
^FO20,526^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FD^FS
^FO370,524^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FD05/15/14^FS
^FO421,614^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDFOR:^FS
^FO427,691^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,711^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,650^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO163,914^BY2,3.0,203^B3N,N,203,N,N^FR^FDRC051514E^FS
^FO45,862^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDRC051514E^FS
^FO427,61^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,102^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,122^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO549,610^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FDCUST NO:^FS
^FO650,610^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FD^FS
^FO345,406^CI0^A0N,39,78^FR^FDPQ^FS
^FO447,406^CI0^A0N,39,78^FR^FD1^FS
^FO650,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD,^FS
^FO671,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO711,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO650,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD,^FS
^FO671,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO711,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

Comment: Hi, to anyone who still cares I ended up spending an hour and a half on the phone with Zebra and they determined that since my printer model was emulating ZPL support I had to be much more careful about the order of the statements by coordinates. In other words, Zebra models with ZPL emulation cannot deal with it when a statement has a x and y coordinates that would make it precede a line already done. It will print but cause weird things like page feeds to happen. So make sure to put all of your lines in order, even if you generate your code using software like LabelViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up spending an hour and a half on the phone with Zebra and they determined that since my printer model was emulating ZPL support I had to be much more careful about the order of the statements by coordinates. In other words, Zebra models with ZPL emulation cannot deal with it when a statement has a x and y coordinates that would make it precede a line already done. It will print but cause weird things like page feeds to happen. So make sure to put all of your lines in order, even if you generate your code using software like LabelViewer.

Answer (score 0):

What size media are you using? Is it gap or continuous? What settings are saved on the printer before this label is sent? You might be in a different print mode, and then when this label is sent it changes it to non-continuous gap mode (^MNY) and then it tries to find the gap by feeding a label.

Does it work if you only send this?

```
^XA
^FO0,398^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO406,0^FR^GB2,236,2^FS
^FO0,606^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO455,234^FR^GB2,165,2^FS
^FO0,843^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO2,232^FR^GB811,2,2^FS
^FO412,604^FR^GB2,240,2^FS
^FO41,41^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDFrom:^FS
^FO427,41^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDTo:^FS
^FO41,264^BY2,2.0,102^B3N,N,102,N,N^FR^FD^FS
^FO22,248^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FDOrder Number:^FS
^FO463,238^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDCarrier:^FS
^FO488,264^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO22,412^CI0^ABN,22,14^FR^FDORDER#^FS
^FO49,443^CI0^A0N,28,56^FR^FD^FS
^FO41,61^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDRandom Address^FS
^FO41,102^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDOne Industrial Rd^FS
^FO41,122^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDSuite 199^FS
^FO41,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FDThistown, PA 12345^FS
^FO20,508^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FDP.O.#^FS
^FO366,508^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FDSHIP DATE^FS
^FO20,526^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FD^FS
^FO370,524^CI0^ABN,11,14^FR^FD05/15/14^FS
^FO421,614^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDFOR:^FS
^FO427,691^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,711^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,650^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO163,914^BY2,3.0,203^B3N,N,203,N,N^FR^FDRC051514E^FS
^FO45,862^CI0^ADN,18,20^FR^FDRC051514E^FS
^FO427,61^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,102^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,122^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO549,610^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FDCUST NO:^FS
^FO650,610^CI0^A0N,17,17^FR^FD^FS
^FO345,406^CI0^A0N,39,78^FR^FDPQ^FS
^FO447,406^CI0^A0N,39,78^FR^FD1^FS
^FO650,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD,^FS
^FO671,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO711,142^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO427,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO650,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD,^FS
^FO671,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^FO711,732^CI0^A0N,23,23^FR^FD^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't told us the height of the label you are using, and we can only imply you're using a 203dpi printer from

```
^FO163,914^BY2,3.0,203^B3N,N,203,N,N^FR^FDRC051514E^FS
```

I suspect that this particular line is your trigger. The resultant label height is 914+203=1117 dots; at 203.2 dpi=5.497", if calculated at 203dpi is a little over 5.5". Now assuming you are using 5.5" labels with a 1/16" gap, this is probably a smidgin too big. Try reducing the 203s to 190 or the 914 a little. In fact, if you temporarily remove this line and the resultant label prints OK, then that's a quick-and-dirty test that should prove the point.